# Teleporting the player to instantiated prefab position

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am instantiating prefabs and listing them on a scroll list. I am trying to teleport the player to instantiated prefab position when I click its reference on scroll list listing?

Comment: StackOverflow is not for asking "Someone (tell me how to) implement XY" but rather "I have this specific situation where I am trying to achieve XY, here is what I researched and tried so far but instead ZZ happens, what am I doing wrong?" - I would suggest to take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Then when you have a specific coding related issue come here again with a new question ;)

Comment: Please provide information on the scroll list, the instantiation and what you have tried. Can I assume you mean moving instantaneously from A to B when you say teleport?

Comment: derHugo - I will definitely improvise next time. Will definitely work on your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand about your problem (explained in the comments rather than the question), you should be able to do this:

You can instantaneously move an object `camera` by setting its transform's position to the instantiated prefab's position when the click has occurred. For a camera, you probably have the camera view in X and Y dimension, so you want to move it to the new X and Y position but leave the Z-position as it is.

One potential solution: Add the following script to the GameObject with your Button component. Then add an event-listener on the Button component that points to the newly added script component and choose the MyTeleportingButton.OnClick as the target method. You also need to drag in the camera as a reference in the new script component.

```cs
public class MyTeleportingButton : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject camera;

    public void OnClick()
    {
        // casting to Vector2 in order to move in 2D only
        var currentPosition = camera.transform.position;
        var newPosition = transform.position;
    
        // set same depth as camera
        newPosition.z = currentPosition.z;

        camera.transform.position = newPosition;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have posted an image, pls have a look.

Comment: I am instantiating a prefab in-game, then once the message is sent it is listed on the scroll list. I want to go back to the instantiated prefab in-game on click on the scroll list reference. Thank You.

Comment: @ankitsharma there is no player in the image. so I don't understand what you mean by "I want to go back".

Comment: The game object on the game view is an instantiated prefab and the same instantiated prefab has its reference on the scroll list. I want to reach the instantiated prefab location by clicking its reference on the scroll list.

Comment: @ankitsharma What is the object that you want to move/teleport?

Comment: The camera focus. I am reading, and now i am confused whether it is teleport or pop up.

Comment: Ok, the camera focus. Now, do you have a Button component on your scroll list?

Comment: yes, I have a button component.

Comment: @ankitsharma Edited. Try this.

Comment: Something like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dz1Jik5U1ls   I am trying to create in my game.

Comment: At 1:05 time event

Comment: Tested the code update.  I have attached the video of the game here https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1VYyemVvcVbKyI8ZOEVVOuPDqQCwkFdOc?usp=sharing. Please have a look.